# Subsetting lists of lists in R

Tags: r

How does one go about subsetting lists of lists in R?

For example I have this list:

```
[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[[6]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 111


[[6]][[2]]
[[6]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[6]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 11


[[6]][[3]]
[[6]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 11

[[6]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[6]][[4]]
[[6]][[4]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[6]][[4]][[2]]
[1] 1

[[6]][[4]][[3]]
[1] 1
```

and I'm trying to get all parts of the list that have 2 sublists or less.  So in this example the output would be the first five sublists,

```
[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[[6]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 111


[[6]][[2]]
[[6]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[6]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 11


[[6]][[3]]
[[6]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 11

[[6]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is called `lst`, then try

```
lst[lengths(lst) <= 2]
```

Comment: Oh my god LIFESAVER.  I literally spent like 2 hours trying to get which statements to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @rdevn00b np, glad it helped

Comment: One more question as well, what would you do if you have another list of say [[5]].  How would you loop through both?  I'm trying lapply but can't get it to work.

Comment: @rdevn00b maybe `lapply(list(lst1, lst2), function(x) x[lengths(x)<=2])`, then you would have a list of the two shortened lists

Comment: Yea I ended up using lapply(c(1:length(foo)), function(x) lapply(foo[x], function(y) y[lengths(y)<=length(slots[[x]])]))